# Uncaught Error: Call to a member function connection() on null in php

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, illuminate-container

I try to use the Eloquent without using Laravel in my project and
I'm getting this error

> Uncaught Error: Call to a member function connection() on null

When I try to call some Eloquent methods.

For example the create method in my createTask function

> ```
> <?php
>
> class HomeController extends Controller{
>
>     protected $task;
>
>     public function __construct(){
>         $this->task = $this->setModel("Task");
>     }
>
>     public function index($name = ""){
>         $task = $this->task;
>         $task->username = $name;
>
>         $this->setView("home/index", ["name" => $task->username, "email" => $task->email] );
>
>     }
>
>     public function createTask($username = "", $email = "", $task = "")
>     {
>         $this->task->create([
>             "username" => $username,
>             "email" => $email,
>             "task" => $task
>         ]);
>     }
>
> }
>
> ?>
> ```

Routing works good, so here is the Model

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;

class Task extends Eloquent
{
    protected $fillable = ["username", "email", "task"];
}

?>
```

What Am I doing wrong? All the connection values are correct too

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager as Capsule;

$capsule = new Capsule;

$capsule->addConnection([
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'database' => 'todomvc',
    'charset' => "utf8",
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix' => ''
]);

$capsule->bootEloquent();

?>
```

Answer (score -1):

You made a mistake in your namespace by typing `Capluse` instead of `Capsule`

```php
use Illuminate\Database\Capluse\Manager as Capsule;
```

Comment: OMG it is so shammy, thank you! Still not working :(